# How to call a sub view from another sub view in xcode

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller, subviews

I had a main view name "View control" and two sub views view1 and view2... My application loads with view1 as a sub view in the main view .. I had a "Next" button on main view . when I press it..view1 should be replaced with view2 with in the main view... Any idea?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Can you post Some code what you tried yet? How you are adding the subview? same way you can remove it from parent view and replace with another view.

Comment: aViewController = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController"  bundle:nil];
    aViewController.showLogin = NO;
    [self.containerView addSubview:aViewController.view];
    companyLogoImage.hidden = YES;

Comment: now am in HomeViewController . Now I want to replace this HomeViewController with another subview .. And the code for replacing the subview should be written in HomeViewController subview

Comment: My Main Aim is to Call a subview from another subview... Is it possible?

Comment: You can use NSNotification centre in Mainview. And fire the notification in one subview to Replace the Subview in main view.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use NSNotificationCenter.

Assuming you have 3 views, One main view and 2 subviews.

> Main view = ContainerView
>
> Subview1= HomeViewController
>
> Subview2= nextViewcontroller

in Subview1 use following code.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ChangetoView2" object:nil];
```

in Subview2 use following code.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ChangetoView1" object:nil];
```

use the below code in the init method of ContainerView.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(ChangeTheView1:) name:@"ChangetoView1" object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(ChangeTheView2:) name:@"ChangetoView2" object:nil];
```

And in the same class use the following function.

```
- (void)ChangeTheView1:(NSNotification *)notification
{
   // Change  here.
[bViewcontroller.view RemoveFromSuperview];
aViewController = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil]; 
aViewController.showLogin = NO; 
[self.containerView addSubview:aViewController.view];
 companyLogoImage.hidden = YES;
}

- (void)ChangeTheView2:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [aViewcontroller.view RemoveFromSuperview];
    bViewController = [[SomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SomeViewController" bundle:nil]; 
    [self.containerView addSubview:bViewController.view];
}
```